# Is there any way for ficus lib to inject in scala case class either Long or String depending on the value in configuration

Tags: scala, configuration

I'm parsing configuration in scala case class with [ficus library](https://github.com/iheartradio/ficus)
Case class approximately looks like this

```
case class Entity(value: Any)
```

and configuration

```
{
  value = "something"
}
```

value might be number or string.
But `config.as[Entity]("pathToConfig")` returns value as `java.lang.Object` with nothing.
How do I make ficus inject in value a Long or String depending on value in configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ) You see, as I said `returns value as Object with nothing`. So casting won't help because `value` neither long nor string inside.

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I did not understand that. I have been playing with the library and it seems there is no way to support that out of the box. [**pureconfig**](https://pureconfig.github.io/) does provide a way to do it, but it requires some modifications to both your case class and the config, also it is mandatory that you know vefore hand which types could be there. If you are interested I can post an answer showing that.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already found a cunning way to do what I want)) I'll post the answer later

Answer (score 1):

I created a ValueReader for this particular `Entity` class like this

```
  implicit val entityReader: ValueReader[Entity] = ValueReader.relative { config =>
    config.getAnyRef("value") match {
      case value: java.lang.Integer => Entity(value.toLong)
      case value => Entity(value)
    }
  }
```

This way `value` inside `Entity` either String or Long